# How to continue with If-Conditions in Try-Catch

Tags: java, try-catch

I have this line of Code

```
try {
        String txtText = article.getTxtText().toString();
        if (StringUtils.hasText(article.getTxtText().toString())){
            textPropertyList.add(txtText);
        }
        String txtLongText = article.getObjLongTextData().toString();
        if (StringUtils.hasText(txtLongText)){
            textPropertyList.add(txtLongText);
        }
        String txtShortText = article.getObjShortTeaserData().toString();
        if (StringUtils.hasText(txtShortText)) {
            textPropertyList.add(txtShortText);
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

    }
```

It is possible, that only one of the three properties are set. But if one property isnt set, I get this NullpointerException. I catch it, but then the try-Block isnt continued.

So e.g. if the article.getTxtText() method returns null, I dont get the txtLongText and txtShortText Strings either, although at least one of them has a not empty String set.

So the question is, how can I continue the try-block although there's is an Exception caught?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why don't you just check for nulls rather than allowing the `NullPointerException` to be thrown?

Comment: Agree with @MarkRhodes, exceptions are much more processor-consuming than a simple `if` to check for nulls.

Comment: oh yes, this is a good idea. i'm gonna try it. thanks :).

Answer (score 6):

You should either use 3 try-catch blocks or just use a null-check around every case.

```
if (article.getTxtText() != null) {
  // do part 1
}

if (article.getObjLongTextData() != null) {
  // do part 2
}
```

Comment: The question was : So the question is, how can I continue the try-block although there's is an Exception caught? This is not the answer to the question, this is another answer ...

Answer (score 3):

I would imagine that the correct approach to this is to have three try/catch blocks around each point of code. The whole point of a try block is that you are trying the code as a lump and if it fails anywhere you abandon it. For what you are describing you would need three try/catches around each possible point of failure.

That having been said you are probably better off testing for null rather than relying on exception handling to do that. Exception handling should be for exceptionalm unforeseen events, not for flow control in a program.

Answer (score 2):

If you must do this with exceptions (and I don't think you should), then you need to have 3 separate try/catch blocks:

```
try {
        String txtText = article.getTxtText().toString();
        if (StringUtils.hasText(article.getTxtText().toString())){
            textPropertyList.add(txtText);
        }
} catch (NullPointerException e) {}
try {
        String txtLongText = article.getObjLongTextData().toString();
        if (StringUtils.hasText(txtLongText)){
            textPropertyList.add(txtLongText);
        }
} catch (NullPointerException e) {}
try {
        String txtShortText = article.getObjShortTeaserData().toString();
        if (StringUtils.hasText(txtShortText)) {
            textPropertyList.add(txtShortText);
        }
} catch (NullPointerException e) {}
```

Once an exception is thrown in your code you cannot restart execution in the middle of the `try` block.

Having said that I would always prefer to detect the null pointer with an `if` test rather than relying on exception handling for this non-exceptional condition.

Comment: eugh - instead of simply checking for null?

Comment: @Nim Well of course you should check for `null`. That's what I said. But I was trying to help the person asking the question understand exceptions.

Comment: This is correct , this is the response to a precise question by the OP : So the question is, how can I continue the try-block although there's is an Exception caught?

Answer (score 1):

do [defensive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) ,check for nulls.

```
if ( variable != null ){

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and better approach from my point of view would be break the try - catch block in  three different try-catch block, something like the following :

```
try {
        String txtText = article.getTxtText().toString();
        if (StringUtils.hasText(article.getTxtText().toString())){
            textPropertyList.add(txtText);
        }

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      //Handle Exception
    }

try {
        String txtLongText = article.getObjLongTextData().toString();
        if (StringUtils.hasText(txtLongText)){
            textPropertyList.add(txtLongText);
        }

 } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      //Handle Exception
    }

try {
        String txtShortText = article.getObjShortTeaserData().toString();
        if (StringUtils.hasText(txtShortText)) {
            textPropertyList.add(txtShortText);
        }
     } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      //Handle Exception
    }
```

Comment: -2 but i have responded to a specific question by the OP, the question was specific : So the question is, how can I continue the try-block although there's is an Exception caught?    -2 for a correct answer ... There is someone here that think to be a professor but don't really read the questions ...

Comment: Well, I gave you an upvote because I think the downvotes were harsh, but your first sentence is asking for downvotes. Using exceptions for this is not the best solution. The best solution is to test with an `if`. A little re-wording could have saved you from all the downvotes!

Comment: It is not matter of downvotes, i don't care about, and i'm on this forum to learn, but i think that if an answer respond to a question should not be downvoted, however i'm here to learn and to help someone else if i can, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a different design:

```
private void addProperty(Object property, Collection<String> properties) {
  if (property == null) {
    return;
  }

  String textProperty = property.toString();
  if (StringUtils.hasText()) {
    properties.add(textProperty);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
addProperty(article.getTxtText());
// ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you doing this in a try / catch, just use simple if

```
if ( txtText != null ){
    ...
}
if ( txtLongText != null ){
    ...
}
```

Comment: that won't work, presumably the `toString()` will throw the `NullPointerException` you have to test `article.getTxtText()`